# How to scrape data from Highcharts using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, highcharts, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from the chart at https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290. I tried accessing the data using the respective xpath of the data in the boxes, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried using Scrapy:

```
date = response.xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-0"]/div/span/b[1]').get()
market_value =  response.xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-0"]/div/span/b[1]').get()
club = response.xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-0"]/div/span/b[3]').get()
age = response.xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-0"]/div/span/b[4]').get()
```

How can I scrape all the data from the chart using Scrapy or Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

This data is being rendered on the client (browser) after consuming an inline JS on the HTML body.

You need regex if you're about to use scrapy

eg (not tested)

```py
import re
import json

body = response.body()
data = re.findall(r"(?<=\'series\'\:).*?}}]}]", body)

if not data:
   return None

data = json.loads(data[0])
```

Comment: It works without the `json.loads()`. I will try uit with regex. If no other solution is given, I will accept your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

temp = driver.execute_script('return window.Highcharts.charts[0]'
                             '.series[0].options.data')
data = [item for item in temp]
print(data)
```